# What's a regular expression that will match comma-quotation-comma?

Tags: c#, csv, ssis

I'm working on a CSV file where all values are surrounded by quotations and separated by commas. In some instances there is a single quotation between two commas and I want to replace such strings with a single comma. This is part of an ETL extraction.

Comment: Do you mean you want to find `,",` in a file of `"value","value"`? Are you whitespace-sensitive? Some example values of what you have and what you expect to match would help.

Comment: Yes, I wand to find [,",] in a file of ["value","value"].  The dirty data is equivalent to ["value",","value"].

Answer (score 0):

A regex is not necessary in SSIS to replace `,',` by `,` , this can be done via derived column and REPLACE function as in this example:

[image]

here the column that is being changes is called Name and the replace expression is

```
REPLACE([Name], ",'," , ",")
```

Comment: I will attempt this solution.  To clarify, however, I'm trying to replace comma-doublequote-comma (,",) with comma (,).  My source file contain about 1.4 million rows of comma-separated values having double-quote text qualifiers.  I'm good until around row 930K where there is a random extra entry of ,", between the third and fourth columns.

Answer (score 0):

To use the [`Regex.Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=net-5.0#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Replace_System_String_System_Text_RegularExpressions_MatchEvaluator_System_Int32_) method, include the [`RegularExpressions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions?view=net-5.0) namespace:

```cs
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Then declare an instance using your pattern `,",` and the [`Compiled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions?view=net-5.0) option which should boost your performance considering you're reading millions of lines.

```cs
var regex = new Regex(",\",", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

Then replace the matches with a comma `,`:

```cs
var data = "\"value\",\",\"value\",\"value\"\n"
         + "\"value\",\"value\",\"value\"\n" 
         + "\"value\",\",\"value\",\"value\"\n";

var result = regex.Replace(data, ",");
```

`data` would be your CSV via something like [`ReadAllLines()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=net-5.0).

[Try it out!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/jOF3qU)

Comment: I like this solution; it's clean.  But it doesn't work for me.  I'm using ReadAllLines()

var data = File.ReadAllLines(strSourceFile);
var result = regex.Replace(data, ",");

Comment: I like this solution; it's clean.  But I get errors.

var regex = new Regex(",\",", RegexOptions.Compiled);
var data = File.ReadAllLines(strSourceFile);
var result = regex.Replace(data, ",");

The error is on 'data':  Cannot convert from 'string[]' to 'string'.

Note:  I'm a newbie on stackoverflow and C#.  Consequently, I haven't figured out how to include the proper formatting.

Comment: I probably should have been clearer. With `ReadAllLines()` you'd have to iterate through the lines, but you'd be able to keep them separate. If you don't need that, you can read the whole file into a `string` with [`ReadAllText()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=net-5.0) instead. Do you have a preference? I'll edit the answer either way.

Comment: P.S. Code blocks in comments are: `\`code\``.

Comment: I changed my code to the following and it worked.

`string strSourceFile;
string strDestinationFile;

strSourceFile = (string)Dts.Variables["varSourceFile"].Value;
strDestinationFile = (string)Dts.Variables["varDestinationFile"].Value;

var regex = new Regex(",\",", RegexOptions.Compiled);
string data = File.ReadAllText(strSourceFile);
string result = regex.Replace(data, ",");

File.WriteAllText(strDestinationFile, result);`

Comment: P.S. I wrapped my `code` with the tick marks but it didn't work as a block.  I'll study markdown help and get it right.